# Entity Framework 6 DBContext disable delete option

Tags: dbcontext, entity-framework-6

Anyone please help me on how to disable DELETE option in EF6?

I mean from the application, now record should be deleted (even accidentally)

Thanks.

Comment: One can disable deletes by pure code:
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38318311/3202422)

Comment: Disable deletes can be done by pure code. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38318311/3202422)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a user/role in the database that does not have permissions to delete/modify records and use it in your application. EF itself is not meant to be a security tool and there are always options to perform a delete operation (e.g. a developer can send any arbitrary SQL query/command to the database bypassing all the 'security' measures implemented in the data access layer)

Comment: Dear Pawl - Excellent. I am sure, this is the best way to do.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

When getting the entities call with `AsNoTracking()` option.

eg :- `Context.Users.AsNoTracking()`

Edit after Stevens Comment

Its true that anyone can still go and change the entity state to Deleted manually. I would recommend, using `Repository Pattern` for data access and can restrict delete operation. By hiding the DbContext outside of the assembly.

Comment: This would prevent you from deleting something from a query easily. But this would not prevent someone from attaching an object, setting it to `EntityState.Deleted` and saving the changes.

Comment: Dear Saanch - Thanks for your reply.  By doing this way, we have to set this option each and every time we use dbContext. Below Mr.Pawel suggesting the best way. Thanks.