# Entity framework: disable delete globally

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We are starting a new application. We want to use Entity Framework. We are little afraid of deleting sql rows accidentally (especially by set related data accidentally etc.)

I thought to disable every delete, since we just mark every row with "validUntil" column and never delete rows.

I saw [that it can done by roles in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20309150/3202422), but I want that all logic and control will be just in code.

Maybe in Entity Framework core there is new feature to enable that? I know that it can still write row sql with EF, but we don't afraid of such case.

I also tried remove setters of entities relationships to be more relax, but it broke the normal functionality of EF, and did not look like a good idea.

I saw in the above link a recommendation to use the Repository Pattern, but [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/220126) it looks like it is not good practice.

How can I work safely with EF? 
thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The role option is one way, but you can also override [SaveChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716714(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (DbEntityEntry entity in this.ChangeTracker.Entries)
    {
        if (entity.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted)
            return;        
    }

    base.SaveChanges();
}
```

**EDIT**

I read on git that for [EF Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3815):

> If you want to change the delete behavior for all relationships, then
>   you can use this code in OnModelCreating(...) to bulk set it for all
>   relationships in your model.

```
foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
{
    relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
}
```

Comment: It isn't working. I have account with one-to-many subscriptions.
account id==13 has one subscription (id==5).
now I set var x =  _context.Accounts.Include(b => b.Subscriptions).First(a => a.AccountId == 13);
then x.Subscriptions = null;

now in override save changes no entity with state==deleted exists, but once saveChanges done subscription id==5 deleted from db...

Comment: Are you using EF 6 or EF Core?

Comment: Core. I changed delete cascade to strict, so it solved this situation

Answer (score 1):

William's answer is pretty much the way to do it, but you can also do something like this.

Set the Delete to throw an exception, and add a DeleteVirtual method. Primarily this is also update, where you can do the soft delete you want via updating the validUntil field.

```
    T IDbContext.Delete<T>(T entity)
    {
         throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    T IDbContext.DeleteVirtual<T>(T entity)
    {
        this.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        return entity;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override `SaveChanges()` method in `DbContext` class and in there you can get a list of deleted entities and change their `Status` to `Unchanged`.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var DeletedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

    DeletedEntities.ForEach(E => 
    {
        E.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    });

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It isn't working. I have account with one-to-many subscriptions. account id==13 has one subscription (id==5). now I set var x = _context.Accounts.Include(b => b.Subscriptions).First(a => a.AccountId == 13); then x.Subscriptions = null; now in override save changes no entity with state==deleted exists, but once saveChanges done subscription id==5 deleted from db...